# Remote Events -- ItemEventProperties.BeforeProperties is always empty?

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, azure, remote-event-receiver

I am playing around with Provider Hosted Apps and Remote Event Receivers to see how everything works. I have a Provider Hosted App set up with the SharePoint component in SharePoint Online, and the web component set up in Azure Websites.

I am using JSOM (not CSOM) on the `default.aspx` page of the web to read and update a list provisioned to the app web, and that is all working fine.

I've set up event receivers for:

- `ItemAdding`
- `ItemAdded`
- `ItemUpdating`
- `ItemUpdated`

I have remote debugging set up so I can see when the events hit the web service.  I see the "ings" correctly hit `ProcessEvent()` and the "eds" correctly hit `ProcessOneWayEvent()`.

The problem is, the `BeforeProperties` is **always** empty.  Now I can understand that `BeforeProperties` might be empty for something like `ItemAdding`, because at that point there was no "before", but shouldn't there be both `BeforeProperties` and `AfterProperties` for `ItemUpdating` and/or `ItemUpdated`?

Anyone have any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: Me too facing same issue. RemoteEventProperties.ItemEventProperties.BeforeProperties is empty in ItemUpdating for CustomList. Is this issue still hanging around ? Anyone familiar with workarounds to make this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remember that

- BeforeProperties and AfterProperties are different for Sync. and Async. events
- BeforeProperties and AfterProperties behavior is different for List Items and Library Items
- If you investigate and test BeforeProperties and AfterProperties behavior in these cases - be ready that it could be all broken if you use Publishing template site

Check for beggining [this](http://srisharepointdevelopment.blogspot.com/2013/06/beforeproperties-and-afterproperties-in.html) table of values, but test independently in Your environment

Comment: Aha, so according to that table, `BeforeProperties` is only ever used on Document Libraries, it is never populated with data for regular lists, and I am using a custom list.  So I will never see `BeforeProperties`.

Comment: NB - the table linked to suggests using `properties.ListItem` to get at some of the values (like original values for regular list items), however, for SP2013 *remote* events, there is no `ListItem` property on the `SPRemoteEventProperties` object.  So it looks like for remote event receivers there is no way to find "before" properties for a list item, and no workaround.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.eventreceivers.spremoteeventproperties_members.aspx

Comment: In some events ListItem could be used, in others(example Adding) - there is no ListItem object at all yet(it is not constructed yet, You will know it's Id and properties later in "Added" event), so properties.AfterProperties["field"] is used instead.

Comment: I don't think you understood my point.  In the [`SPItemEventProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties_members.aspx) class, there is a property `ListItem`.  Yes, maybe in some situations it will be `null`.  However, in the [`SPRemoteItemEventProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.eventreceivers.spremoteitemeventproperties_members.aspx) class, *there is no property for* `ListItem`.  So for *remote* event receivers, there is no workaround to get to that information.

Comment: Yes, but You still have properties.Before/AfterProperties or properties.ItemEventProperties.Before/AfterProperties? If doesn't help then imho You should store or get the listItem object especially inside Your request

Comment: Right, but the problem then becomes - for `itemUpdated`, the item has already changed, so you can't get the item and make a comparison to what it was.  For `itemUpdating`... making an AJAX call to retrieve a list item in the middle of a synchronous event is bound do cause bad timing issues.

Comment: Don't know Your situation. Possibly You can make a temp hidden field [tmpValue], and store previous value there..